# Variable from read-host not working in select-object

Tags: powershell, active-directory

i encountered a problem when trying to build a small read-host script that pipes the result into an AD script:

when doing an AD search, i can select objects like that:

```
get-aduser exampleuser | select-object name,enabled
```

though when i enter

> name,enabled

into the read-host that stores the input as a variable which later gets used in the script, it turns into this:

```
name,enabled
------------
{}
```

instead of this (when typing it manually)

```
get-adcomputer CTXTEST | select-object name,enabled

name    enabled
----    -------
CTXTEST   False
```

I assume that I overlook something rather simple, but I tried a lot of things and didnt find a solution through master Google.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thats because the `Select-Object` cmdlet takes an **array** of strings, the `Read-Host` cmdlet only returns a singe string, even if the string contains a comma.

You can simply create an array by splitting the input on a comma. (I also use the regex to trim whitespaces):

```
$selectResult = (Read-Host "Which properties?") -split '\s*,\s*'
```

Comment: Nice. I usually do `-split ',' |% Trim` to avoid excess whitespace

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen wow, and I didn't know that you can invoke Trim like that  :-). So I can invoke any member method like that?

Comment: i was about to add this as i just found out this works aswell - i split it up at the "," and it works just fine. it feels sloppy and messy, but i guess its fine if noone ever sees it

Comment: Sure, but if you enter  `name, enabled` then your select will fail.